# Set up mandril with mail catcher in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailcatcher

I am using mandril with action mailer.
On my mandril config

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:port =>           '587',
:address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
:user_name =>      ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
:password =>       ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'],
:domain =>         ENV['MANDRILL_DOMAIN'],
:authentication => :plain
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

MandrillMailer.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY']
end

Rails.application.config do |config|
   config.mandrill_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['DEFAULT_URL_HOST'] }
config.mandrill_mailer.default_url_options['protocol'] = ENV['DEFAULT_URL_PROTOCOL'] unless ENV['DEFAULT_URL_PROTOCOL'].blank?
end
```

On the action_mailer.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['DEFAULT_URL_HOST'] }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options['protocol'] = ENV['DEFAULT_URL_PROTOCOL'] unless ENV['DEFAULT_URL_PROTOCOL'].blank?
end
```

On the development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

I am running mail catcher and visiting http://localhost:1080/ but it doesn't work, 
do I need to add more configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the default smpt_settings with mailcatcher in dev mode. so I didnt specify the

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = ..
```

at all.

But I have to launch mailcatcher in the foreground with

```
mailcatcher -f
```

for it to work (it's somehow buggy as deamon). This has the advantage, that you can see if it receives the mail requests.